# cross validation process

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am working on a voice morphing system. I have source speech signal (divided into test, train  & validation) and target speech signal (divided into test, train and validation data). Now I'am designing a radial basis neural network with 3 fold cross validation to find the morphed speech wavelet coefficients. I need to initialize the net with source and target training data and perform 3 fold cross validation using training and validation samples.

I think that as per the cross validation I need to divide my data set into 3 parts and then use 2 of them for training and the other for testing. (Repeating the process for all the folds). Now the problem is that I want to know that weather I need to divide my source training data into 3 parts or the target training...??

Thus I need to know how to apply the cross validation? Can anyone please elaborate the process for me?

Comment: Do you need help with the "how to implement this" part or the conceptual part? if it is the concepts you'd better ask this in the signal processing (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Kritika: it sounds like your question is really mostly about the cross-validation process. You might get more specific help if you edit the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should randomly divide your entire data (tuples of input ["source"] and output ["target"/"morphed"] observations) into 3 sets: training, cross-validation, and test.

The training set will be used to train each neural network you try. The cross-validation set will be used after each network is trained, in order to select the best parameters (# of hidden nodes, etc, etc). The test set is used at the end to validate the overall performance (i.e. accuracy, generalization, etc.) of the final model.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I need to combine the source and target data and then divide it into 3 sets?

Comment: @Kritika: Well, if I understand what you're doing, there is a 1:1 relationship between "source" and "target" records, so yes. You're trying to learn a function from some inputs (the "source" observations) to some outputs (the "target" observations), so you need to break the "combined" (if you want to call it that) data set of (source, target) tuples into three parts.